# Clarifying a step in a proof of Jordan–Hölder theorem in an abelian category

Tags: category-theory, proof-explanation

> Let $\mathscr{C}$ be an abelian category. Let $A\in\mathscr{C}$ be
> both Noetherian and Artinian. Given filtrations $$0\subset A_1\subset
>  A_2\subset\dotsb\subset A_n=A \quad\text{and}\quad 0\subset B_1\subset
>  B_2\subset\dotsb\subset B_m=A$$ such that $A_i/A_{i-1}$ and
> $B_i/B_{i-1}$ are simple objects, we have $m=n$ and there exists a
> permutation $\sigma$ of $\{1,\dotsc,n\}$ such that $A_i/A_{i-1}\cong
>  B_{\sigma(i)}/B_{\sigma(i)-1}$.

There is a proof of the above given [here](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0FCD) (Lemma 12.9.7) , which I’m trying to understand. The proof begins as follows:

> Let $j$ be the smallest index such that $A_1\subset B_j$. Then the morphism
> $A_1\rightarrow B_j/B_{j-1}$ is an isomorphism...

Why is $A_1\rightarrow B_j/B_{j-1}$ an isomorphism?

By definition of $j$, we know that $\neg(B_{j-1}\subset A_1)$. On the other hand, we know that $B_j/B_{j-1}$ is simple, i.e., its only subobjects are $0$ and itself. How do I deduce that $A_1\rightarrow B_j/B_{j-1}$ is an isomorphism from these two facts?

Comment: The idea for say abelian groups or modules over a ring is to say that the homomorphism is surjective since the codomain is simple and injective since the domain is simple. (and it is not the 0 map) Try translating that into the language of abelian categories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $A_1$ is simple - you sort of get that by treating $A_0=0$ so that $A_1 = A_1/A_0$ is a simple object, and in any case the statement is not going to be true if $A_1$ is allowed to not be simple.

So the kernel of $A_1 \rightarrow B_j/B_{j-1}$ is $0$. That means the image as the cokernel of the kernel is isomorphic to $A_1$.

At the same time the image is a non-zero subobject of $B_j/B_{j-1}$, and so since $B_j/B_{j-1}$ is simple that inclusion must be an isomorphism.

Put together, that means that both parts of the image factorisation of $A_1 \rightarrow B_j/B_{j-1}$ are isomorphisms, so the entire morphism is an isomorphism.